# Is there any physical significance of the Lorentz transformations not having a group structure?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory

I was studying transformations in QFT and I saw that Lorentz transformations do not have a closed group structure. If $K_i's$ are the generators of the Lorentz transformations and $J_i's$ are the generators of rotations, we have

$$[K_i,K_j]=-\epsilon_{ijk}J_k$$

However, the generators of both the Lorentz transformations and rotations *together* give us the Lorentz group (which is a closed group).

This seems fairly straightforward in terms of the derivations involved, but does this have some more non-trivial and deeper significance which I am unable to decipher?

Comment: This fact has a name ‘Thomas precession’. You can read up the wiki page for it to learn more.

Comment: One possible "deeper significance" is the observation that it is impossible to have a theory invariant under boosts that is not also rotation invariant.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/68586/276737 Does this answer your question?

Comment: What you’re calling Lorentz transformations are known as Lorentz boosts. Both boosts and rotations are considered Lorentz transformations, as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).

Comment: In addition to reading about Thomas precession, you should read about [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation), which is more fundamental.